# Fetching only last 100 or so files (most recent files) from an S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm building a process that will send customizable alerts based on the last received date of a file to an S3 bucket.

Because my bucket is huge, doing something like this takes a **very** long time to run:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id='demo', aws_secret_access_key='demo')

my_bucket = s3.Bucket('demo')

bucket_items = my_bucket.objects.all():
```

I could of course simply do the above, and then sort by the `last_modified` attribute, but I wonder whether there's a more elegant way to sift out just the 100 most recent files themselves when the API call is being made.

Ideally, I'd also want to be able to customize this even further with search strings - i.e. I might want the 100 most recent files that have ".docx" in the file name, or I might want the most recent files above 1MB in size - etc.

Just wondering what the best practices are for this kind of querying when the contents of the entire bucket are not needed.

Comment: Does it have to be real-time? What about using [s3 inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) once a day to get a csv with the objects. The csv would be much easier and quicker to process.

Comment: Doesn't have to be literally real-time, but I'd like to run this script every 2-3 hours - just so if there's an interruption in us receiving any files, we find out about it in a matter of hours, and therefore have a chance of fixing the issue on the same day it's discovered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your available options are:

- **Retrieve a list of objects** from the bucket: But this is slow if you have a large number of objects (10,000+) -- but using Prefixes can make this a lot faster, *or*
- **Obtain a daily listing** via [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html): But it sounds like you want information more up-to-date than daily, *or*
- **Maintain your own database** of objects

To maintain your own database of objects:

- Create an Amazon S3 event that triggers an AWS Lambda function whenever objects are created/updated/deleted
- The AWS Lambda function should store this information in a database (you would need to write this functionality)
- You can then query the database for all of your requirements

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer. Using lambdas to build and maintain a db is a bit overkill for my situation, so sadly it looks like I'll just have to stick to retrieving a list of all objects each time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

About the 100 most recent files, you can use list_objects in boto3. In return, there are 'LastModified' field to sort and get the file needed.
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects

For filtering, you can use this code to list all objects and add some code to download using something like this.

```
srcbucket = 'bucket'
srckey = 'object'
obj = s3.Object(srcbucket, srckey)
```